# Add ceiling to datetime (non-fixed frequency)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to add a ceiling to a resampled datetime index using Business Day frequency. I get this error:

> ValueError: <3 * BusinessDays> is a non-fixed frequency

`ceiling = df.index.ceil('3B')`

2020-01-08 00:00:00
2020-01-13 00:00:00
2020-01-16 00:00:00
2020-01-21 00:00:00
2020-01-24 00:00:00

Is there a solution to this? thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us what the expected out put should be. Rounding dates can be tricky as it is ambiguous.

Comment: Also, this post might be of interest to you: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15303